# Geo Chart US State not showing totals when displaying the specific provinces

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to just display a map of each state which works, but when I specify the state the totals do not display. But if I display the entire US the states show the totals. Let me show you what I am seeing.

If I set my region to just `region: 'US'` I see the following which works fine and shows the total for the state of NY

[image]

If I change my region to `region: 'US-NY'` I see the state but the totals are not there.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
    'mapsApiKey': '************************************'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Total'],
            ['New York', 130689],
        ]);
    var options = {
        region: 'US-NY',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: "provinces",
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

am I missing something? seems to work fine here...

the first time took a second or so to load,
but it is working for me...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyBgxLAOHUq52CuZ0kcl9WHnOjzt40w082k'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['State', 'Total'],
      ['New York', 130689],
    ]);
    var options = {
        region: 'US-NY',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: "provinces",
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: found out the problem, apparently, you can't use the same `mapsApiKey` for multiple world maps.